# Ring of endomorphisms of a simple module is a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I am a beginner in Module theory. One of the problems in Artin's "Algebra" book ask to prove the following:

Prove that the ring of endomorphisms of a simple module is a field.

My attempt:

I can easily sho it is a Division ring using Schur's Lemma. But how to show it is a commutative ring or it is a type in question.

Thanks for any insight!!

Comment: Yeah, it need not be commutative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can very easily verified that every non-zero endomorphism $\varphi$ over simple $R$-module $M$ is bijective.

Because these two holds...

$$0\le\ker\varphi\ne M, 0\ne\mathrm{im}\varphi\le M$$
and $R$-sumbodule of $M$ is only $0, M$.

But it is not a field. If $R$ is non-commutative, then there exists $a,b\in R$ such that $ab\ne ba$, and $L_a, L_b:M\to M$ such that $L_a(m)=am, L_b(m)=bm$ are not commutative.

When $R$ is commutative, then there exists maximal ideal $m$ such that $M\cong\frac Rm$ by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/377707/simple-module-is-isomorphic-to-r-m-where-m-is-a-maximal-ideal). And $\frac Rm$ is field!

Every endomorphism over field is $L(x)=kx$ form. And left is easy to verify.

Comment: So, is it a typo in the book?

Comment: @BhawanaDey I think so. When $R$ is commutative, the assertion is true, but there is an counterexample when $R$ is non-commutative.

Comment: If the ring of endomorphisms is finite, then it follows from Schur's lemma and Wedderburn's little theorem that it is a field.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131005/discussion-between-nightflight-and-eloiprime).